# How to implement dynamic columns with MatGridList?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, grid

I have a Mat-Grid-List which displays an array of data. I want to have the *cols* property to be dynamic. The cols amount depends on the with of my box. I have put my code into [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-grid-list-cols).
It should also recalculate the columns when the box gets resized. At this moment get the following error and the function gets only called one time:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'cols: 2'. Current value: 'cols: 6'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `resize` event to grid itself as your resize event is not firing

```
  <mat-grid-list [cols]="columns" rowHeight="100px" width="100%" (window:resize)="onBoxResize($event)">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-grid-list-cols-alprdz)

Comment: ok this is working now on resize but it should also call the function when the grid gets initialized. How to do that?

Comment: add `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook and call it eg `ngAfterViewInit(){//call you resize method here}`

Comment: In `ngAfterViewInit` I get my described error. I solved it by putting the call in `ngAfterContentChecked` life cycle hook.

Comment: @JuNe ok one thing accepted answer is copy of this answer how that can be accepted

Comment: Changed it. Sry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the setter `ViewChild` at all. Just create a simple function called `setColumns` which updates the `columns` in the HTML. Use the `window:resize` event in the HTML to call this function and also call it in `ngOnInit` to make it resize on load.

```js
@ViewChild('box', {static: true}) box: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.setColumns();
}

setColumns() {
    this.columns = Math.floor(this.box.nativeElement.clientWidth / 100);
}
```

In the template, just call `setColumns` on `window:resize`.

```html
<mat-grid-list [cols]="columns" (window:resize)="setColumns()" rowHeight="100px" width="100%">
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resize-grid-list).

Comment: You are right. But I have to call the function in `ngAfterViewChecked` and not in `ngOnInit`

Comment: Why so? That would again be called anytime any part of the view is changed. If you call it in `ngOnInit`, it will be called once on load and the rest will be take care of by the `window:resize` event